# write each line of a text file into separate text files and save them with a different names

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file which contains the following value:

```
('Yellow_Hat_Person', [293, 997, [...]], [328, 1031, [...]])

('Yellow_Hat_Person', [292, 998, [...]], [326, 1032, [...]])

('Yellow_Hat_Person', [290, 997, [...]], [324, 1030, [...]])

('Yellow_Hat_Person', [288, 997, [...]], [321, 1028, [...]])

('Yellow_Hat_Person', [286, 995, [...]], [319, 1026, [...]]
```

I want to write each line into separate text files and save them with a different names. eg. line 1 should be passed to a text file and it should be saved as 1.txt, line to should be passed to a different text file and it should be saves ad 2.txt, line 3 passed to a different text file and saved as 3.txt and so on. Any suggestions would be helpful. The language i am using is python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over the lines of the file, and create a file for each line:

```
with open("text_file.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        with open(f"{i+1}.txt", "w") as g:
            g.write(line)
```

If you are on an older Python 3 version (3.5 and below), you replace the third line with

```
        with open("{}.txt".format(i+1), "w") as g:
```